# Complex LINQ request and odd int increment behavior

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling with a complex LINQ request.

I created a List of 8 colors in an helper class (ColorTools). I wanted to pass those colors as an Object instanciation parameter.

Knowing that I create up to 5 of those objects, I created a counter which I increment each time I create one of those objects and get the corresponding Color in my List.

But what happens is that I get an OutOfRangeException.

```
Dictionary<ItemVM, int> topItem = DisplayedAlarmOccurrences
    .Select(ao => ao.Item)
    .GroupBy(t => t)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Count())
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Value)
    .Take(5)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);

//topItem countains up to 5 elements here
int cpt = 0;

int maxOccItem = topItem.Any() ? topItem.Values.Max() : 10;
SummaryParetoVM summaryItem = new SummaryParetoVM(
    "Items",
    new Axis("Number of Items", 0, maxOccItem),
    topItem.Select(t => new ParetoSerie(
        new []{
            new ParetoInformationPlacement(Place.MIDDLE_CENTER,
                new InformationPlacement()
                {
                    Information = "n° ",
                    Value = t.Key.Index.ToString()
                }),
                new ParetoInformationPlacement(Place.RIGHT_CENTER,
                    new InformationPlacement()
                    {
                        Information = null,
                        Value = t.Value.ToString()
                    }
                )
            }
        )
        {
            //cpt will have a value of 8 here, how is it possible when topItem only got up to 5 items?
            Points = new[]
            {
                new ParetoValuePoint(t.Value,
                    t.Key.Index.ToString(),
                    ColorTools.ChartingBrushes[cpt++])
            }, 
            Title = "Top Items"
        }
    ).Cast<Serie>()
);
```

So the exception happens in the ParetoValuePoint instanciation where I pass

```
ColorTools.ChartingBrushes[cpt++]
```

as a parameter to the ParetoValuePoint constructor.

I tried to increment cpt using Interlocked.Increment but cpt will get incremented to 8 and the exception appear the same way.

NB: it's only a test code so the code cleanliness is irrelevant here, I just would like to know how the counter's value is over 5.

Edit ChartingBrushes is a public static readonly List which is initiated in the static constructor of a static class. Here is the code:

```
public readonly static List<Brush> ChartingBrushes;
static ColorTools() {
    ChartingBrushes = new List<Brush>{
        new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(115, 115, 115)),
        new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(241, 90, 96)),
        new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(122, 195, 106)),
        new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(90, 155, 212)),
        new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(250, 167, 91)),
        new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(158, 103, 171)),
        new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(206, 112, 88)),
        new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(215, 127, 180))
    };

    ChartingBrushes.ForEach(b => b.Freeze());
}
```

Comment: Is `ColorTools.ChartingBrushes` initialized with items ?

Comment: It looks like the constructor takes an IEnumerable parameter. If the enumeration is enumerated multiple times, cpt could be bigger. You could add `ToList()` after the cast, or better yet, use a Select with index `(value,index)=>'  instead of the variable

Comment: @Ofiris I edited the post to explain how ChartingBrushes is initialized

Comment: @Me.Name Indeed, adding .ToList() after the .Cast<Serie>() prevent the exception from happening. Could you post an answer with a detailed explanation? Thank you

Comment: My guess would be that you enumerate the collection `topItem.Select...Cast<Serie>()` at least twice, and in each enumeration the `ParetoSerie` contructor is called (10 times with 2 enumerations). Calling `.ToList()` enumerates the collection once and stores the results in a list. Every following enumeration fetches the result from the list and not calculates the result from scratch.

Comment: @Grx70 it seems so indeed. Adding .ToList() as suggested by Me.Name prevent the exception from happening. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enumerable isn't 'closed'. That is, each enumeration increases `cpt`. If you would add a `ToList()`, the enumeration would only run once and a list would be created with the results:

```
.Cast<Serie>().ToList()
```

Besides that, there is a [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) overload that takes an index, which prevents dependency on a variable. By using the index, the problem would be prevented also, but each object would be created on each enumeration. Best is the combination of the overload and the ToList.

An example of what happens without creating a list or other collection

```
    int[] values = new int[4];
    int cntr = 0;

    var enumerable = values.Select(i => cntr++);
    foreach (var i in enumerable)
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    foreach (var i in enumerable)
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    //at this point counter is 8, because the enumeration has run twice. If ToList would be appended to the Select, the result would be 4.
```

An example with the combined ToList and the Select with index:

```
             int[] values = new int[4];
             var list = values.Select((value, index) => index).ToList();
```